# Word Wrap on basic Android Notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

Here is how I do my basic `Notification`:

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setContentTitle("Title")
                                .setContentText(msg);

                mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                mNotificationManager.notify(NID, mBuilder.build());
```

I am not using the `BigViewStyle`,  just your *basic* notification.  If the incoming `msg` is too long, it doesn't show the entire sentence.  Is there anyway to do this without using `BigViewStyle`?

Comment: is there a particular reason you are avoiding using the Big View Style?, it was created for that purpose

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast I guess you are correct.  I will do it that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to do this without using BigViewStyle?

No, simply because the size of a regular `Notification` is limited.